# Select specific radio options when a checkbox is checked jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

So, I have a form with a group of dynamic radio buttons like below:

```
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_AM" value="4"><label for="Manager_Staff_Score_AM" style="padding-right: 15px"> AM (4)</label>
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_AE" value="3"><label for="Manager_Staff_Score_AE" style="padding-right: 15px"> AE (3)</label>
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_PA" value="2"><label for="Manager_Staff_Score_PA" style="padding-right: 15px"> PA (2)</label>
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_UR" value="1"><label for="Manager_Staff_Score_UR" style="padding-right: 15px"> UR (1)</label>
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="Manager_Staff_Score" id="Manager_Staff_Score_NR" value="0" class="NR"><label for="Manager_Staff_Score_NR" style="padding-right: 15px"> NOT RATABLE</label>

<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_AO_1" value="5" <label for="employee_cce_score_AO_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> AO (5)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_AM_1" value="4"><label for="employee_cce_score_AM_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> AM (4)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_AE_1" value="3"><label for="employee_cce_score_AE_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> AE (3)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_PA_1" value="2"><label for="employee_cce_score_PA_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> PA (2)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_UR_1" value="1"><label for="employee_cce_score_UR_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> UR (1)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_100" id="employee_cce_score_NR_1" value="0" class="NR"><label for="employee_cce_score_NR_1" style="padding-right: 15px"> NOT RATABLE</label>

<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_AO_2" value="5" <label for="employee_cce_score_AO_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> AO (5)</label>
<input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_AM_2" value="4"><label for="employee_cce_score_AM_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> AM (4)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_AE_2" value="3"><label for="employee_cce_score_AE_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> AE (3)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_PA_2" value="2"><label for="employee_cce_score_PA_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> PA (2)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_UR_2" value="1"><label for="employee_cce_score_UR_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> UR (1)</label>
    <input type="radio" style="margin-right: 3px" name="employee_cce_score_200" id="employee_cce_score_NR_2" value="0" class="NR"><label for="employee_cce_score_NR_2" style="padding-right: 15px"> NOT RATABLE</label>
```

Now I have a checkbox above all of these radio button options:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="not_ratable" id="not_ratable" class="form-control">
```

When the above checkbox is check, I need to have all of the class elements of "NR" checked **or** all the inputs with a value of "0" checked, either way is fine with me unless there are 'best practices'. My jQuery is below and not working. :)

```
$('#not_ratable').click(function () {
    $('.NR').prop('checked',this.checked);
});

$('.NR').change(function () {
    if ($('.NR:checked').length == $('.NR').length){
        $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',true);
    }
    else {
        $('#not_ratable').prop('checked',false);
    }
});
```

Currently what doesn't work is if another radio option is selected, the checkbox stays checked.

Comment: The first solution works for me.

Comment: Where are you executing your javascript in relation to your page markup?  Possible document ready issue

Comment: Seems fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/8bjx740z/

Comment: Make sure you're running the code inside `$(document).ready`

Comment: Or a delegate event handler since they are "dynamic radio buttons"

Comment: Also note that the HTML you posted is broken. 2 input tags are missing the closing bracket.

Comment: Okay, so I feel stupid!! I had the class element on the label and not the input element. OMG!!!! Now, it works when checked and unchecked, but what doesn't work is if another radio option is selected, the checkbox stays checked. Thoughts!

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Comment: Thanks matthias_h, probably a typo when copying code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To uncheck the checkbox when another radio option is checked you can do the following:

```
 $("input[type='radio'][class!='NR']").click(function(){
    $("#not_ratable").prop("checked", false);
 });
```

Comment: Do I add that to my function or replace something I have with that?

Comment: @DavidJacobson you add that to your functions.

Comment: Hmmmm, I did that but it's not unchecking the checkbox element when I click a different radio option. Do the other radio options also need a class tag??

Comment: Strange, it's working here https://jsfiddle.net/zd12xhwo/ and I didn't change anything of your code.

Comment: Weird, I copied what was is jsfiddle and it started working. Guess I had something in my code differently. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad I was able to help :)